# What is the language name of the output tab in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

First Problem: The indent rainbow extension is also giving errors for the Output tab(i.e. the one for build tasks output and certain extension logs). I do not want this.

Solution: Use the exclude language setting.

However, I can't find the language ID for the output tab. I've tried "plaintext" and "output". Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: https://github.com/oderwat/vscode-indent-rainbow/issues/49

Comment: @ATP That disables ALLL of them instead of just the output.

Comment: https://github.com/oderwat/vscode-indent-rainbow/issues/16

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't give me a fix, and I'm sure that it's this plugin since the extension settings work on it.